# How I can convert ampl file to cplex?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl, glpk

I wrote a model in Ampl and I wanted to solve it by glpk. But I noticed that I need some cplex's operation such that ==>, and glpk does not have it. I am wondering is there an easy way to convert Ampl file to cplex? or it is a difficult process and I have to rewrite every thing in Cplex format!
(I did not buy ampl so I can not use cplex in ampl)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "CPLEX format"? CPLEX supports a number of different file formats. As far as I know you can export LP or SAV files from AMPL.
The question is whether glpk can read these files then. Maybe you need some glpk-compatible format rather than a CPLEX-compatible format?

Comment: So I can run ampl file by cplex?

Comment: No. But from AMPL you can export a file that CPLEX can read. Just google for "AMPL" and "LP" or "AMPL" and "MPS" and you will find a lot of discussions that explain how to generate an LP or MPS file from AMPL. CPLEX can read LP and MPS. Maybe there even is a way to export a SAV file. That would be the best.

But again, if you want to solve with CPLEX then you can call this from AMPL directly, or not? Generating a CPLEX file does not mean you have a file that glpk can read. You will have to try whether glpk understands.
See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/kjBCs-4dXbY

Comment: @DanielJunglas I have cplex solver, I will run it by cplex if I can convert .mod file to lp

Comment: If you have the CPLEX solver then you can use that directly from AMPL. The google dicussion I linked above has some instructions about that. In fact, it tells how you can export an MPS file (which can then be read by CPLEX) and how you could alternatively use CPLEX from AMPL directly (by means of cplexampl).

Comment: @Daniel Junglas, `write( "xx.lp" )` from that groups.google link doesn't work in the limited student AMPL: "# Unknown option outopt truss.lp (-otruss.lp)"

Comment: What if you attempt to output to `truss.mps` instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the AMPL software, then you cannot run AMPL files and convert them automatically to any form.

The GLPK package does have its own modeling language, GNU Mathprog, which implements a linear subset of AMPL. Thus sometimes it is not so hard to translate an AMPL model to a GNU Mathprog model. Then GLPK can process the GNU Mathprog model and produce an MPS or LP file that can be read by a solver.

GNU Mathprog does not have the `==>` ("implies") operator found in AMPL, however, so any AMPL constraints using that operator will have to be translated into linear constraints. There are well-known ways to make such a translation. If you need help with doing it, then that should be posted as a separate question. (You will have the best chance of getting an answer if you show the complete AMPL constraint that you are trying to translate.)